# Dielectric Slab Waveguide

Tags: dielectric, waveguide

I have a question about dielectric slab waveguides. In these type of waveguides, n1>n2. What would happen in the case of n2>n1? I think there would be no propogation through the waveguide, but I am not sure how to show this mathematically with the maxwell equations.

[image: Dielectric slabe waveguide]

Answer (score 0):

In the case where n2  > n1, the light won't be bound to the structure as a spatial mode.   That being said you can certainly get light to propagate, as a 'free space' mode, and it will emerge from the other side.  The specifics of what happens depends upon the dimensions of the slab.

I should note that in your structure even in the n2<n1 case, there isn't a bound mode in the lateral dimension.  The light is still freely propagating.

Answer (score -1):

Use Snell's law, and ray tracing, and you will soon see that this version does not contain the rays except for the ones perfectly parallel to the interface.  In other words, it leaks!  The other design refracts the rays back into the structure.

Comment: if it was  that simple goubau waves would not exist http://www.nedyn.com/Goubau_1951-X.pdf

Comment: @hyportnex: an elementary question requires an elementary answer.  Otherwise one is assuming that everybody is a graduate student, and that in order to provide an answer, one must be willing to write an academic thesis!